# boost exception with a zero-length tuple, how to workaround

Tags: c++, boost

I've run into a limitation using boost exception and make_tuple with zero arguments. Essentially I have a macro like this:

```
#define MAKE_EXCEPT( msg, ... ) exception( msg ) << make_tuple(__VAR_ARGS__)
```

Where the variables arguments will be various error_info types. *The above is simplified from the full macro, I've just pulled out the bit causing me trouble.*

The problem is that if there are no arguments I get an error above no `operator<<` defined for the involved types.  That is, although `make_tuple()` is well defined (I even used it elsewhere) the overload with exception doesn't work here.

I'm looking now to make a workaround. So instead of using the operator directly I wrap it in a function:

```
#define MAKE_EXCEPT( msg, ... ) make_except( exception( msg ), make_tuple(__VAR_ARGS__) )
```

Now, the question is how do I specialize this function? I need a version that works with the normal tuples and one with the null_tuple.

Comment: Does your compiler has variadic templates or not? And did you check the Boost FAQ (may be worth a bug report)?

Comment: No C++11 support (gcc may have it, but we don't use it yet).  I also suspect this is a minor defect in the libraries -- it feels like it should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found something that works. This seems overly complicated. Perhaps somebody else has a better/simpler solution.

In this code `make_except` is called `error_with_tags`

```
template<typename E, typename T,int CNT>
struct error_with_tags_helper
{
    E const & operator()( E const & x, T const & t )
    {
        x << t;
        return x;
    }
};

template<typename E, typename T>
struct error_with_tags_helper<E,T,0>
{
    E const & operator()( E const & x, T const & t )
    {
        return x;
    }
};

template<typename E, typename T>
inline E const & error_with_tags( E const & x, T const & t )
{
    error_with_tags_helper<E,T,boost::tuples::length<T>::value> et;
    return et(x,t);
}
```

Comment: I also created the ticket https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6374 and it looks like the Boost team have fixed it.